# examples for subset of R

Tags: real-analysis

1) a subset of R that is neither closed nor bounded
(-infinity , 0) U (0 infinity) does this work?

2) a subset of R whose derived set, which contains all its point, is the interval (0,1)
Could not think of an example for this? Is this impossible?

3) a subset of R whose only limit point is 1
Could not think of an example for this? Is this impossible?

Comment: what's a derived set?  Is it the set of all limit points of a set?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ is neither closed nor bounded.
2. For any set $A$, the derived set of $A$ is closed, and $(0,1)$ is not closed, so $(0,1)$ cannot be the derived set of any $A\subseteq\Bbb R$.
3. Consider a set whose points are a sequence of distinct points converging to $1$.